# Quasar QUploader with multiple files and factory function showing second file has failed

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, quasar

I have a QUploader which which is set to upload multiple files to a Laravel api. It is working as expected, the files are uploaded, Laravel processes them and then sends the response.

The problem is quasar thinks that any subsequent files have failed. The first file fires the @uploaded event, subsequent files fire the @failed event.

Here is some of my code:

```
    <q-uploader
            ref="uploader"
            label="Upload media"
            style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%"
            class="q-mb-md"
            :factory="uploadImage"
            multiple
            @added="added"
            @uploading="uploading"
            @uploaded="uploaded"
            @failed="uploadFailed"
          >
```

```
    const uploadImage = (files) => {
      const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve({
          url: API_URL + "/api/uploadMedia",
          method: "POST",
          headers: [
            {
              name: "Authorization",
              value: `Bearer ${authStore.token}`,
            },
          ],
          fieldName: "file",
          formFields: [
            { name: "id", value: item.id},
            { name: "notes", value: image.commentText },
            { name: "closeUp", value: image.closeUp },
          ],
        });
      });
    };
```

This is what I'm seeing in the Network tab for the two images I'm uploaded (Both are uploading successfully)):

[image]